# How can I install lightdm-webkit2-greeter?

Tags: software-installation, lightdm

I want to install this: https://github.com/Antergos/web-greeter

I'm not sure how to use the given OBS Repo to install the package. I've done quite a bit of googling and I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that OBS repo is perplexing to me as well. I would build from source:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-whither
sudo apt-get install liblightdm-gobject-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-gi
git clone https://github.com/Antergos/web-greeter.git /tmp/greeter
cd /tmp/greeter
sudo make install
```

Comment: These commands are not working for Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, I get the following error: `E: Unable to locate package python3-whither` and `E: Unable to locate package liblightdm-gobject-dev`, Is there any alternate method to install it?

Comment: @galoget I just posted another answer that should work for you. Took a bunch of digging to figure it out for myself.

Answer (score 2):

For people from 2019+ who are coming across this thread, I solved it by installing it from source too, however you have to get the dependencies as follows:

- Install [Whither](https://github.com/Antergos/whither) (another package by Antegros)

  - Install its dependencies:

    ```
    # Make sure you have pip installed (python's package manager)
    sudo apt install python-pip

    # Install PyQt5 WebEngine
    sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine
    ```
  - Install using pip (this didn't work for me)

    ```
    sudo pip install whither
    ```
  - Install from source

    ```
    git clone https://github.com/Antergos/whither.git
    cd whither
    sudo python3 setup.py install
    ```
- Install other dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install liblightdm-gobject-1-dev
  sudo apt-get install python3-gi
  ```
- Finally install [lightdm-webkit2-greeter](https://github.com/Antergos/web-greeter)

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/Antergos/web-greeter.git
  cd web-greeter
  sudo make install
  ```

Themes can be found at `/usr/share/web-greeter/themes`

**Main Config** file is at `/etc/lightdm/web-greeter.yml`

**Enable** `lightdm` to use `web-greeter` by editing/creating a file at `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-web-greeter.conf` as follows:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=web-greeter
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a fork of lightdm-webkit2-greeter, which solves it from not being usable, as well as adding new features. You can find it at [web-greeter](https://github.com/JezerM/web-greeter). Also, I made another greeter based on Electron.js, you can find it at [nody-greeter](https://github.com/JezerM/nody-greeter).

To install web-greeter, first install all the common dependencies: `liblightdm-gobject-1-dev python3-gi python3-pyqt5 python3-pyqt5.qtwebengine python3-ruamel.yaml python3-pyinotify libqt5webengine5 gobject-introspection libxcb1-dev libx11-dev`. As well as the build dependencies: `rsync make base-devel node-typescript`.

Then, clone it and install:

```sh
git clone --recursive https://github.com/JezerM/web-greeter.git
cd web-greeter
sudo make install
```

Also, latest releases provides debian and ubuntu `.deb` packages for x86 if you do not want to build it by yourself. See [here](https://github.com/JezerM/web-greeter/releases/latest).