# How to install lightdm-webkit-greeter2 on ubuntu

Tags: gnome, 17.04, lightdm, webkit

I was wondering if anyone knew how to install the lightdm-webkit-greeter 2 on ubuntu 17.04.

I have looked at the github page, and I can't install any of the dependencies it needs as they all return a package not found. Any help would be appreciated as I really do want to use this greeter

I have seen this post, ([How can I install lightdm-webkit2-greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960334/how-can-i-install-lightdm-webkit2-greeter)) and I have tried it, but as stated above none of the dependencies are in the apt-get command

Comment: edited to make it more clear that attempting to get the dependencies through apt does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the only possible solution for this, is to have a Ubuntu version where those dependencies are available.

In the following links you can find which versions of Ubuntu have them:

- [liblightdm-gobject-1-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=liblightdm-gobject-1-dev)
- [python3-wither](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-wither)
- [python3-gi](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-gi)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: I will try this, I can change the repository versions from 17.04 to 16 or even older, I will attempt this and see how it ends up, thank you for your help

Comment: Hope it works, don-t forget to mark the question as answered and vote for the correct answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

to compile web-greeter on ubuntu you will need to:

1. install Dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install liblightdm-gobject-1-dev gobject-introspection libgirepository1.0-dev pyqt5-dev-tools libcairo2-dev
   ```
2. install Python libs

   ```
   sudo -H pip3 install whither 
   sudo -H pip3 install pygobject
   ```
3. then you can:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/Antergos/web-greeter.git /tmp/greeter
   cd /tmp/greeter
   sudo make install
   ```

NOTE1: tested on ubuntu 18.04 using python3.6, didn't work on ubuntu 16.04 using Python 3.5

NOTE2: whither package will install Qt 5.10.1, but it has a bug QTBUG-66346 it affects Qt 5.10.1 and 5.9.4. You have to downgrade PyQt5 to 5.10.0

```
sudo -H pip3 uninstall PyQt5 

sudo -H pip3 install  PyQt5==5.10.0
```

> You can run the greeter from within your desktop session if you add the following line to the desktop file for your session located in /usr/share/xsessions/: X-LightDM-Allow-Greeter=true.
>
> You have to log out and log back in after adding that line. Then you can run the greeter from command line.
>
> web-greeter

Answer (score 1):

Compile and install required software. If you don't find it in a deb package on somebody else's server, that's what we do when we "really" want to run a program that nobody has packaged.

That's what being a Linux user is all about! I am not teasing...

Comment: Thank you for your response, If the method of changing my repo version to that of an older ubuntu version does not work I will attempt to compile them myself. Once again thank you for your time